# Siremis with Nginx how?

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to deploy Siremis 5.3.0 (https://siremis.asipto.com/2020/02/) on Ubuntu 22.04 running Nginx. There is very little information on running Siremis on Nginx on the web. I got everything installed properly (I think), but I am having a problem with the Nginx configuration to properly serve the pages.

I'm almost sure that the problem is in the URL rewrites. I can go to this page no problem:

DOMAIN/siremis/index.php/user/login

But I get Page Not Found after that with this URL:

DOMAIN/siremis/system/general_default

But, Siremis is another matter. I'm not sure if Siremis just doesn't support working with Nginx because it expects Apache when performing redirects or what. Just wondering if anyone has any suggestions. I'm new to Nginx, obviously. Or if anyone knows how to turn off the redirects in Siremis, that would be fine too! I don't need to have the "pretty" URLs.

Here's my server configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
  

    charset utf-8;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/siremis.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/siremis.error.log;

    root /var/www/html/siremis-5.3.0;
    index index.php;

    server_name sip1.<<DOMAIN>>;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    error_page 404 = @router;
    location @router {
        if ($uri ~* (^/siremis)(.*)$) {
            set $val1 $1;
            set $val2 $2;
            rewrite .* $val1/index.php$val2 redirect;
        }
        rewrite .* /siremis/errTest.html last;
        internal;
    }

    location =/ {
        rewrite .* /siremis redirect;
    }

    location /siremis {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /siremis/index.php$is_args$args
    }

    location /siremis/install {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /siremis/index.php$is_args$args
    }

    location ~^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; 
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        try_files /siremis/favicon.ico =200;
    }

    # Кэширование статических файлов
    location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js)$ {
        add_header 'Content-Type:$content_type' 'Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=144000s';
    }
}
```

Try it [Running Siremis web on Nginx:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599774/running-siremis-web-on-nginx)
and try it https://lists.kamailio.org/pipermail/sr-users/2011-January/066937.html

not working :(